# How to create a login, user, and give rights over database in SQL Azure?

Tags: sql, azure

I am trying to give permissions to a user I just created and has a login associated logged into my master.

I was not able to give any permissions since it says you do not have permissions to do this.

I gave myself dbowner rights in the master but still.

Any help?

Might it be that the database I created does not have the schema dbo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
I thought you said the user you added didn't have any permissions, my bad! Well the answer still might be helpful :-)

I'm not an SQL expert so this may not answer your question, but I had to do something like this today and listing my steps might help.

You can use a graphical tool like [Azure User Management Console (AUMC)](http://aumc.codeplex.com/) if you want to add users without having to write a bunch of SQL queries.

Connect to your server, go to Logins and create a new login (if you want to give server access as well), then go to Users, select your database, create a new user, then here you can link the user to the login you just created and give database permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation on granting users/logins permissions:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/06/21/10028038.aspx

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'readonlyuser';
```